# SSIS System.TimeSpan to MSSQL Field time(7)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Having a VERY VERY annoying issue with a Slowly Changing Dimension task in SSIS.

This data flow task starts with a Script Component that is a Source that grabs data from a web API.

> Script Task Data Source

In this data there is a *Time field* which comes into the Script as a string **"14:21"** for instance.

I have a piece of code that does a convert from string to timespan `ConvertStringToTime("14:21");`

which works fine, changing the value to a `System.TimeSpan` format **"14:21:00"**.

> Script Task Data Source Output

The value is then written to an output field with a data type of **database time [DT_DBTIME]** *(Running a data view here shows the data is all correct and looks good)*

> The Conversion

I have now recently to attempt to fix this issue added in a Conversion task that takes this value and converts it to a **database time stamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]**

> Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) - **The Issue**

Now this is where the issue start, I pass this row to my (SCD) and map it to a field in my MSSQL database that has a **time(7)** data type.

I receive the following error from the SCD GUI while using the converted and unconverted data fields:

**Column 1 is of type 'System.DateTime' and column 2 is of type
 'System.Object'.**

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: So you know, the timestamp datatype has nothing to do with dates, or times. Converting a time (or date) to timestamp will not work, and that is what I am gathering you are trying to do. Timestamps version a row of data; dates and time are used to hold values.

Comment: @R.Richards DT_DBTIMESTAMP in SSIS is not the same as timestamp in SQL Server. it is "A timestamp structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a maximum scale of 3 digits." See MSDN > Integration Services Data Types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141036.aspx

Comment: I stand corrected! Thanks.

Comment: Whoever named these things did a great job, not! ;-)

Comment: Just to try to clarify, we are talking about three different systems: SQL Server, SSIS, and .NET Framework.. Each has its own ways of representing date and time. SQL Server has datetime, datetime2, date, time, etc. .NET Framework has DateTime, TimeSpan, etc. SSIS has half a dozen, see reference above.

Comment: It's also worth having a look at ISO Standard 8601: Data elements and interchange formats - Information interchange - Representation of dates and times. This distinguishes between time points, durations, time intervals, and recurring time intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DT_DBTIME2 in your input to the slowly changing dimension transformation.

DT_DBTIME2 is "A time structure that consists of hour, minute, second, and fractional seconds. The fractional seconds have a maximum scale of 7 digits." See MSDN > Integration Services Data Types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141036.aspx

This is equivalent to the SQL Server time data type.

To demonstrate this, create a simple dimension table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestDimension
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    buskey int NOT NULL,
    [time] time(7) NOT NULL,
    currentrow tinyint NOT NULL
);
```

Create a CSV file to provide input.

[image]

The Flat File Connection Manager which reads the CSV file is configured so that the time column is of type DT_DBTIME2 with DataScale of 7 (meaning the fractional part of seconds has 7 digits) to match the dimension table in the database.

[image]

The data flow looks like this. Flat file source feeds into the Slowly Changing Dimension transformation.

[image]

Inspect the dimension table.

[image]

We can test it again with a second CSV input file. This updates a couple of rows in the dimension table and inserts one new row.

[image]

The data flow looks like this when it runs.

[image]

And the dimension table is updated like so.

[image]

Comment: I want to give you extra points for the level of detail you have gone into here. Time2 just worked thank you for the time you spent on this answer.

Comment: Thank you, it was an interesting question. I've added a couple more comments about dates and times.